# Not able to jump from tableViewCell to another viewController using segue

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, xcode6

Hi I'm new to swift and Xcode 6 so I tried to perform the segue to jump from cell to another viewController shown as below:-

[image: Segue using storyboard]

Also I tried to go programmatically with below code:-

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println("selected row \(indexPath.row)")
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueCust", sender: self)
}
```

Still I'm not able to perform and if run above code then app crash with following error:-

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<swiftDemo.DetailTableViewController: 0x7fdab1606ee0>) has no segue with identifier 'segueCust''
```

No idea why this error is coming as in storyboard I have assigned the segue with this identifier.

Moreover,below segue method is never called.

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!)
```

Also I have add a button and perform segue using storyboard from one viewController to another then it's working fine.
So far I might be missing or doing a silly mistake. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. delete the segue and try to add once again.

Comment: @raghav I did delete it and added it many times. Also tried that segue from button in viewController to another, and it worked out fine in that but over in cell.

Comment: From the looks of it everything looks correct for me. When the segue is connected it will make implicit call to prepareForSegue where as in your case this is not happening. Trial and error method check the **connection inspector window** for prototype cell whether the segue name is mentioned.

Comment: Checking for name would be a later part as in first place that prepareForSegue is not getting called. If u have any link available or anything would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to invoke the segue programmatically with `self.performSegueWithIdentifier`, it needs to be linked from the view controller itself.  (That's what `self` is in your code.)  From your image, you seem to have it connected to the cell rather than the view controller.

(Why the cell connection isn't working automatically, I have no idea.)

Comment: Okay you might be right for self part but I'm able to understand why cell part not working as earlier I have done it on iOS 7 and below version along with Xcode 5 and lesser.

Comment: You have the segue as a 'push'.  Is the view controller on the left inside a navigation controller?

Comment: push as I have programmatically added tableView to navigationController before presenting tableView from my initial VC

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed as below:-

```
 //Embedded my tableVC with navigationController and provided that navigationController a storyboard id.
 //Used that navigationController and presented it on my current VC as below.
 var storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            var vc : UINavigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("naviVC") as UINavigationController

 self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Also connected my tableView cell with another VC(shown below) and rest worked smoothly as it should be.
In below I have provided navigation controller with storyboard id.

[image: Storyboad screenShot]